# bootstrap table no-wrap for elements inside td

Tags: html, spring-boot, maven, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I am trying to create an application using springboot, thymeleaf and bootstrap.
This is the html code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">



<head>


<!-- tried bootstrap; 5 didn't work -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootswatch/4.5.2/darkly/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootswatch@4.5.2/dist/minty/bootstrap.min.css"> -->




</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <br /> <br />
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">

            <div class="container justify-content-center">
                <!-- <a class="navbar-brand"
                    th:href="@{/employee/profile/{employeeId}(employeeId=${employee.employeeId})}">Profile</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
                    data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarColor01"
                    aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button> -->

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0" id="navbarColor01">
                    <!-- <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto justify-content-center"> -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto justify-content-end">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"
                            th:href="@{/employee/profile/{employeeId}(employeeId=${employee.employeeId})}">Profile
                        </a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"
                            th:href="@{/absence/employee/{employeeId}(employeeId=${employee.employeeId})}">Absence
                                Management</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"
                            th:href="@{/overtime/employee/{employeeId}(employeeId=${employee.employeeId})}">Overtime</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"
                            th:href="@{/evaluation/employee/{employeeId}(employeeId=${employee.employeeId})}">Evaluation</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>

                </div>

            </div>
        </nav>


        <h3>Absence Management:</h3>
        <hr />
        <br /> <a
            th:href="@{/absence/employee/add/{employeeId}(employeeId=${employeeId})}"
            class="btn btn-primary">Add Leave</a> <br /> <br /> <br /> <br />

        
            <div class="col-auto">
            
                    <table class="table table-primary table-bordered table-striped white-space: nowrap"
                        id="absence">
                        
                    
                        
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Request Number</th>
                                <th>Starting At</th>
                                <th>Ending In</th>
        
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th style="width: 40.00%">Action</th>
        
        
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="absence: ${absenceDto}">
                                <td th:text="${absence.absenceId}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${#dates.format(absence.startingDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${#dates.format(absence.endingDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${absence.approvedToString}"></td>
        
                                
                                <td>
                                    
                                
            
            
                                        <div th:switch="${absence.submitted}">
            
                                            <a th:case="null"
                                                th:href="@{/absence/submit/{absenceId}(absenceId=${absence.absenceId})}"
                                                class="btn btn-info">Submit </a> <a th:case="true"
                                                th:href="@{/absence/submit/{absenceId}(absenceId=${absence.absenceId})}"
                                                class="btn btn-info disabled" role="button"
                                                aria-disabled="true">Submit </a> <a th:case="false"
                                                th:href="@{/absence/submit/{absenceId}(absenceId=${absence.absenceId})}"
                                                class="btn btn-info">Submit </a>
            
            
                                        </div> <a
                                        th:href="@{/absence/update/{absenceId}(absenceId=${absence.absenceId})}"
                                        class="btn btn-info">Update</a> <a
                                        th:href="@{/absence/delete/{absenceId}(absenceId=${absence.absenceId})}"
                                        class="btn btn-info">Remove</a>
                                    
                                    
                                </td>
                                
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
        
        <br /> <br />
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <a th:href="@{/employee/{employeeId}(employeeId=${employeeId})}">Back
                To List</a>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
```

[image]

If you have a look at the attached image you will find the ACTION column has three buttons :
SUBMIT, UPDATE and REMOVE.

The three buttons are not on the same line . They are wrapped.
Could you help me unwrap them ?

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the "submit" button was putted into a div. That's why you have the wrap.
You have two solutions :
1- You put the "submit" button outside of the div. And make it in the same level like the others buttons
2- You use the Flex Box CSS on the action column (display: flex;)

Comment: I only put them with the same <div>, and it worked :)

Many thanx for the quick reply.